# Have \newgeometry automatically reset after 1 page

Tags: margins, geometry

I would like to adjust the margins for a single page in a document using `\newgemoetry{}` and then have it reset automatically once it goes to the next page without finding the specific word or sentence that it comes after. I realize this package is more oriented towards manual change, but does anyone have a solution for this? For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=.85in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top = 1cm, hmargin=.85in}

XYZ....

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Is there anyway to add a command such that you don't need to add the `\restoregeometry` in the exact right place? (If it helps, I'm only changing the top margin on one page).

Comment: are you sure you want to use `\newgeometry` here rather than simply `\vspace*{1cm}` or whatever you need? (\newgeometry` is highly invasive and you can not change the text width mid-paragraph in TeX so there is no general way to restore it at a page break, but it seems you just want some space at the start?)

Comment: Great idea - this is particularly useful when you need to add a letterhead in the first page of a document as I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use `\newgeometry` here rather than simply

```
\vspace*{1cm}
```

or whatever you need?

(`\newgeometry` is highly invasive and you can not change the text width mid-paragraph in TeX so there is no general way to restore it at a page break.